# Oracle, Pl/SQL: substitution/replace function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing a unique challenge, the problem I'm facing is something like this:

I need to ignore the zero from the input: For example

Example 1 
Input --> 1580 
output --> 158

Example 2 
Input --> 3008 
output --> 38

Is there any built function or through normal query I can solve the above problem or do I need to write custom pl/sql code.

Please suggest.

Comment: `REPLACE(TO_CHAR(yourcol),'0','')`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions167.htm#i78608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
select 3008 original, REPLACE(TO_CHAR(3008), '0', '') replaced from dual;
```

Result:

```
original | replaced
---------|----------
3008     | 38
---------|----------
```